# where can i find the list of all awailable outputs of "lsb_release -si" in linux?

Tags: python, linux, shell, linux-distro

I want to detect a person's distro in linux using python, and I want to do different things depending on a distro and I don't know where I could find such list, I googled it, but found nothing, I also ran `man lsb_release` but I got nothing there, maybe anyone know where i could find such list?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/ try asking here

Comment: @pippo1980 okay

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405709/python-lsb-release-not-working-in-debian-9 first hit searching for lsb_release you can try   https://askubuntu.com/ too I believe its debian_based_linux but not sure

Comment: import lsb_release but apparently this module is not present in all the pythons 3, https://linuxluvr.blogspot.com/2017/05/python-module-lsbrelease.html, you could try that , I am not on linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lsb_release` is a shell script:

```
$ file $(command -v  lsb_release  )
/usr/bin/lsb_release: a /usr/bin/sh script, ASCII text executable
```

so you can open it in your editor and see what it does.

> I want to do different things depending on a distro and I don't know
> where I could find such list

I don't think such list exists, `lsb_release` just reads
`/etc/lsb-release` or local `/etc/[distro]-release` file, as it says
in the comment:

```
# Description:
# Collect informations from sourceable /etc/lsb-release file (present on
# LSB-compliant systems) : LSB_VERSION, DISTRIB_ID, DISTRIB_RELEASE,
# DISTRIB_CODENAME, DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION (all optional).
# Then (if needed) find and parse the /etc/[distro]-release file.
```

For example, on my Slackware system it reads `/etc/lsb-release` and on
Fedora it reads `/etc/redhat-release` so whatever info you put in
there will be reported.